# Texturing Quadrics in JOGL

Tags: opengl, textures, jogl, glu

I can't manage to texture a glu Quadric (gluSphere):
What i get instead of the texture, is an average color of the texture.

```
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_BLEND);
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S); 
gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_GEN_T); 

sunTexture = TextureIO.newTexture(new File("sun.jpg"),false);

float[] rgba = {1f, 1f, 1f};
gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_AMBIENT, rgba, 0);
gl.glMaterialfv(GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_SPECULAR, rgba, 0);
gl.glMaterialf(GL.GL_FRONT, GL.GL_SHININESS, 0.5f);

sunTexture.enable();
sunTexture.bind();
    GLUquadric sun = glu.gluNewQuadric();
    glu.gluQuadricTexture(sun, true);
    glu.gluSphere(sun, 5, DETAIL, DETAIL);
sunTexture.disable();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:
i had set
    gl.glFrustum(-20, 20, -20, 20, 0.1, 400);

after setting
   gl.glFrustum(-20, 20, -20, 20, 1, 400);

it appears ok.

Answer (score 0):

As GLU generates texture coordinates itsself and transmits them as glTexCoord, I think, there is no need to enable texcoord generation (GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S/T). I suppose the GLU-generated texCoords get overwritten with the ones from texgen.

I also see, that you submit an array of three floats to glMaterial, which expects RGBA (4 floats). But since I work with C++, I maybe wrong and this works in JoGL.

Comment: Removing GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S/T will change the texture coordinates. With these removes the texture is very distorted/stretched. With them enabled, the texture is just a solid color.

Comment: But with texgen its just wrong. Or you use texgen and don not call gluQuadricTexture, but there is no builtin texgen for spherical texture coordinates. That's what gluQuadricTexture is for.

Comment: glu should compute the usual latitude-longitude-mapping for spheres (like the latidue/longitude circles on the earth). So you get the t-coordinate from one pole to the other and the s-coordinate 360 degrees around the sphere. If that's not what your sun.jpg is meant for, you'll have to compute the coordinates youself and make your own sphere object. With a normal image as texture, you always get distortion towards the poles, your image has to compensate that.

Comment: It does not matter how i rotate the sphere, the texture is equally distorted, and always wrapped as if one pole is facing straight towards the camera.